# Google spreadsheet as db for web applications

Tags: google-sheets

Does anyone know if I can use Google spreadsheet for storing results of my custom HTML form?

I know that Google spreadsheet allows creating a form on a Google domain itself but is it possible to use Google spreadsheet as db for other webapps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Google Spreadsheets API](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/)

The [Developers's Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html) explains how to use the spreadsheet as a database, and the relevant APIs for adding and retrieving rows.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do that ? What do you think is the response time of Google's Backend when the app gets lot of request ? What is the max request allowed ?